# How much this data fits to a bell curve?

Tags: normal-distribution, ranking

I have stock data of a clothing company.

**Objective:** 
Select which SKUs are most likely to be sold according to:

- Quantity per size per SKU
- Quantity distribution per size per SKU ( I prefer to have many "Medium" size, and less XXS or XXL)

I want a single measure to rank multiples SKU to choose which best fits a standard normal distribution (Skewness and Kurtosis).
I know I can calculate

$ Skew =  $ 
[image]

[image: $ Kurt =]

But I would have only a single value to say if data best fits a bell-shape curve

SKU Size    Quantity

```
A   S   6
A   L   97
A   XL  33
B   L   63
B   S   8
C   XS  18
D   S   1
E   M   2
E   L   3
E   XL  2
E   XXL 1
```

Comment: This feels like an intermediate step and not your actual goal. If so, could you describe your actual goal? I don't see any reason why your data would be normal. Maybe lognormal, but... Again, it feels like you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: I have an overstock of clothes and I want to know which SKUs have a normal distribution of quantity per size. Because these will be the most like to be sold in a short period of time.
I have this data (which I don't know nothing about its distribution) and I want to select which SKU have higher quantity for Medium size and very low quantity for XS or XXL size. (Size is a string and not a number, but let's I can easily convert it to a number)

Comment: So you want SKUs where the quantities of XS and XXL are significantly smaller than the quantities of S, L, and XL , which are significantly smaller than the quantities of M? What if there are no M's (your example A)? What if there is nothing less than M (your example E)? Do your SKUs have to have all sizes represented, or only smaller than M, M, and larger than M, or something else?